# Executing script file in postgres database of keycloak

Tags: postgresql, sh, keycloak, h2

Can anyone help provide a script to import or run the sql exported script in the Keycloak PostgreSQL database?

I'm looking for a script to import database data.

I attempted it but was unsuccessful.

kubectl run psql-postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace ucp --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.7.0-debian-10-r37 --env="PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD"  --command -- psql --host postgresql -U kong -d keycloakdb -p 5432 --file \i keycloak.sql
**psql: warning: extra command-line argument "keycloak.sql" ignored
i: No such file or directory
pod "psql-postgresql-client" deleted**
pod ucp/psql-postgresql-client terminated (Error)